# Register model of computation

Tags: computation-models

It consists of one read only input memory and write only output medium. The computation proper takes place in a working memory of limited size. When stating that a problem can be solved with a certain number of bits, what we mean is that the working memory consists of that many bits. The input and working memories are divided into words of $w$ bits for a fixed parameter $w$. Random access to to input and working memory is provided. In the context of $n$ words, assume as is common , that $w = \theta(\log{n})$.

**Question :** What it means "In the context of $n$ words, assume as is common , that $w = \theta(\log{n})$.
"

**Link :** " Space-efficient Basic Graph Algorithms [Link](http://thiserver.informatik.uni-augsburg.de/personen/kammer/dfs.pdf)"

Comment: Where is the quote from?

Comment: Please make sure to provide proper credit for your sources: see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing for how to reference your sources.

Answer (score 3):

The word RAM is a model of computation in which basic operations operate on words. For example, adding two words costs $O(1)$ in this model. In algorithms class, it is often tacitly assumed that basic operations on indices and on data cost $O(1)$. For example, consider the following program for computing the maximum of an array:

```
calculate-max(A, n):
max = A[1]
i = 2
while i <= n:
  if A[i] > max:
    max = A[i]
  i = i + 1
```

This program is usually assumed to run in $O(n)$. This means that the following operations should all cost $O(1)$:

- Assignment of data points (`max = A[1]`, `max = A[i]`)
- Assignment of indices (`i = 2`, `i = i + 1`)
- Comparison of indices (`i <= n`)
- Comparison of data points (`A[i] > max`)
- Arithmetic on indices (`i + 1`)

In order to accommodate this in the word RAM model, we need to assume that words have length at least $\Omega(\log n)$, since this is the length of indices such as `i` above. Usually words of length $\Theta(\log n)$ are enough for performance of an algorithm in the word RAM to match its performance as perceived by the algorithm designer. Therefore the most common word RAM model is the *logarithmic cost word RAM*, in which words have length $\Theta(\log n)$ (the constant doesn't matter since it only affects the running time by a constant factor).

The only remaining question is – what is $n$? It is usually assumed that $n$ is such that the input is $n$ words long. This definition is a bit circular (since the length of a word depends on $n$), but usually works out nevertheless.